# Can I watch movies with the Rasberry Pi Zero?

Tags: hdmi, video, pi-zero, cpu

I want to make a DIY home-theater system with the Raspberry Zero. My question is will the processor and RAM be enough to play a movie with no problems.

(I am planning to use an HDMI cable and an additional USB stick with the movie)

Comment: yes, as long as the movie is encoded with a codec the pi can handle

Comment: I would actually recommend a Pi 2 or 3, as my b+ struggled to handle files like MKVs. In terms of an OS I would go with Kodi, its got lots of great features, like controlling the Pi with an app on your phone, which I find super useful.

Comment: @DarthVader [Kodi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kodi_(software)#Official_versions) is not an operating system, it is a cross-platform application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**All** Raspberry Pis can play 1080p@30fps provided

- the video is encoded with a codec the Pi can accelerate (i.e. h.264) - note that filename extension
  doesn't always indicate the used codec correctly !
- the video player you use can use hardware acceleration (only Kodi/omxplayer till date)

You might need to buy a MPEG-2 license since the Zero is too weak to software decode such videos.
Interestingly software decoding with unlicensed software is legal in France , for example.

Comment: What is it about MPEG-2 license? Where can I buy one? (Not that I need it, I'm just surprised Pi-zero needs a license to play a format I'd expect to be widely supported)

Comment: All Raspberries are extemely price sensitive products. If you buy a 400$ PC somebody will have paid the license indirectly or directly. The MPEG-LA has never sued consumers AFAIK. If you are a business like Raspberry Pi Trading you should expect to pay for HARDWARE decoders at least. http://www.raspberrypi.com/mpeg-2-license-key/

Comment: Cool, thanks for the link. Now I'm tempted to buy one just to see what I'll get exactly :)

Comment: Software MPEG-2 decoders are fast enough on the Pi2 and the Pi3. How much more can you overclock a Pi Zero ? I assume no responsibility for broken Pis ;)

Comment: I know that. I'm just puzzled about what I'll get if I pay for the license. Firmware file? activation code to put in `config.txt`? Software?

Comment: An activation code which has to be put into config.txt and is non-transferable. If you have multiple Pis and multiple licenses you can seperate the codes with commas and use the same config.txt on all machines.